# How to use windows service to start a software as an administrator?

Tags: c#

My program refers to `Cjwdev.windowsApi` to start the software, but now there is a software that must be run as an administrator, how can I do it?

The following is part of the code:

```
string appStartPath = @"D:\Program Files (x86)\tencent\QQ\Bin\QQScLauncher.exe";
                 
IntPtr userTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                ApiDefinitions.WTSQueryUserToken(ApiDefinitions.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), ref userTokenHandle);

ApiDefinitions.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = new ApiDefinitions.PROCESS_INFORMATION();
ApiDefinitions.STARTUPINFO startInfo = new ApiDefinitions.STARTUPINFO();
startInfo.cb = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(startInfo);

// begin start
ApiDefinitions.CreateProcessAsUser(
                    userTokenHandle,
                    appStartPath,
                    "",
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    false,
                    0,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    null,
                    ref startInfo,
                    out procInfo);

if (userTokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    ApiDefinitions.CloseHandle(userTokenHandle);

int _currentAquariusProcessId = (int)procInfo.dwProcessId;
```

Comment: Note: English only on this Stack Overflow site.

Comment: In [tag:c], there is no such `string` class. Are you asking a question about [tag:c++]?

Comment: This is c# code

Comment: I modified the c# tag but it didn't work